# How to make sure that My Activity doesn't move up when softkeyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-layout

I used hello world app and added an edit-text box to it which I wanted to keep at the bottom. 
Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sarang.hellotext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type Anything"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity looks fine when soft keyboard is hidden. 
However, it moves up completely when soft keyboard is visible (Even the title bar).

[Snapshot with and without soft keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCvHC.png)

Is there a way to avoid this? I would like EditText box to move up, but title-bar and text view should still be visible at the top.

Also, When I removed *android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"* for EditText, the title and textview retains its place irrespective of keyboard. I am not able to understand why?

Comment: Post your complete XML

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your manifiest file under activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and if it doesn't work then

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: I have already tried both options, unfortuantely behaviour remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`  to your activity may well do it. That is, in the AndroidManifest.XML file, put the above line inside the `<activity>` of your app.
I'm not sure why your question now says -1 (but I'm new here.) Granted, the question offers no great insights but at least it's clear what you're asking and everyone has to start somewhere. In your case (well, everybody's really) reading the documentation.  Specific to you, read [Handling Input Method Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond), in particular the "Specify How Your UI Should Respond" bit.

(Ah, I see someone gave similar advice whilst I was typing away... Sorry for the repetition,)

Comment: Thanks for elaborate answer. However I had already spent lot of time trying out adjustPan/Resize , and could not get it to work. Suspecting something in layout.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that, seem to remember it helping... Try wrapping it in a `scrollView` perhaps? To be honest I'm not to hot at using Layouts (well, it gets on me wick) Unfortunately, powerful implies complex.